# Grinding in first gear

Tags: grinding

I have a problem with first gear while slowing down it grinds going into first but when I’m parked up and go to pull away it’s fine and no grinding I’ve just had a new clutch put on would the clutch need more bleeding

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please post the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Once the car is moving, does grinding every appear when downshifting into 3d or 2d ?

Answer (score 0):

First gear on most transmissions doesn't have syncromesh so you'll have to double clutch to get a smooth downshift into first.

They don't need syncromesh because most people don't downshift into first as part of braking/deceleration, but only once the vehicle has come to a standstill.

Recently, I've had two VWs, one (2011 Jetta) is reasonably easy to get into first while rolling, so it may have a syncro on first, while the other (2003 Passat) was nearly impossible to get into first while moving.

If you had a mechanic tell you that this was a clutch issue (and there were no other issues pointing to a clutch failure), I'd say the mechanic got some work out of you for nothing and I would recommend not returning to this guy.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. Most cars have syncromesh on first too. However, the syncro on that gear wears quite easily especially if the driver's habit is to switch into first at motion often. Reverse is the only gear without syncromesh.

Comment: "most people don't downshift into first as part of braking/deceleration" Servicing brake pads is much easier and less expensive than replacing gearbox syncros.